# Safe way to connect database with php using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I just cut down my long code to small so its easy to understand. I am building php based website. I am using `MySQLi` as i know some `MySQL`. And for me `PDO` is hard to learn in small time period.

I created three files

```
 - db.con.php
 - index.php
 - logout.php
```

I will post my all three files and i just want to know if its `safe` or there is any `Vulnerability`

And i thanks to all who see my question and appreciate answer alot.

**db.con.php**

```
<?php
//db.con.php
class DB { 
    protected $db_name = 'demo';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';

    public function connect() { 
        $DBerror = 'Database Error';
        $connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_pass)) or die($DBerror); 
        ((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE $this->db_name")) or die($DBerror); 
        return true; 
    }
} 

$db = new DB();
$db->connect();

//start session
session_start();
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'db.con.php';
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $userID);

$CheckQuery = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$userID'");

$VerifyID = mysqli_num_rows($CheckQuery);
if ($VerifyID !== 1){
    header("Location: logout.php");
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
}

echo "My id is $id and my name is $name";

?>
```

**And last logout.php**

```
<?php
//logout.php
session_start();

session_destroy();
echo "Logout successful";
?>
```

Comment: You are using MySQLi, that means you can use prepared statements.  No more `mysqli_real_escape_string`!  See here: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: Your `$connection` seems too long to me :/

Comment: P.S. You can pass `$this->db_name` as the 4th parameter to `mysqli_connect`.  Also, what's the point of `$connection` if you're just saving the connection into `$GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]`?

Comment: Create a singleton of your connection instead of assigning it to a global

Comment: thanks for the reply guys.. how i can do connection instead of this?

Comment: @RocketHazmat pls suggest connection line thanks

Comment: `$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo");` try something like this

Comment: This question ought to be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Comment: thanks @StillLearnin and Rasclatt

Comment: Run your code seems fine to me except `$connection` you can use this instead `$connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_pass, $this->db_name)) or die($DBerror);`

Comment: I can't see how a connection should matter in order to be "secure". It's the query you need to worry about. If someone gets a hold of your source code, now that's a different story or that you have error checking to display sensitive information (that could happen). *Least, that's "my" opinion.*

Comment: Yes i think same that connection is not a issue here. Seems to me `he/she` means `index.php?userID=1` will be secure or not

Comment: It looks like his code is the result of using the myql->mysqli automated conversion tool. That's where `$GLOBALS["__mysqli_ston"]` comes from, it's the translation of the way mysql automatically defaults the connection resource.

Comment: @DeepakKumar i will use yours connection suggestion. Yeah i mean passing userID's because that is how my site got **hacked** last year. site was **vulnerability**

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, when I said create a singleton instead of assigning to global, I meant as a general comment, not as a "more secure" way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make it PDO not mysqli
2. Leave DB class alone for a while
3. Learn prepared statements

**db.con.php**

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $opt);

session_start();
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'db.con.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['userID']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if(!$row) {
    header("Location: logout.php");
    exit;
}
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
echo "My id is $id and my name is $name";
```

Look it works better without homebrewed wrappers